How to show snackbar above the keyboard
I was having bottom overflow issue (this is so funny) when keyboard is shown, so I set my scaffold resizeToAvoidBottomInset property to false as suggested in a few SO posts.
Doing this fixes the overflow issue but has an unintended consequence where snackbar appears below the keyboard and is thus invisible.
Setting resizeToAvoidBottomInset to true solves the snackbar issue, but the bottom overflow is back!
How can I have my cake and eat it too?

Thanks for SingleChildScrollView solution, Copilot suggested that one too.
I ended up using a different approach, sharing here in case anyone else finds it useful.
On performing the action I close the keyboard. This way the results will be visible without keyboard obstructing the view, and if there are any error, snackbar will be visible too. I preferred this over scroll view approach.
 IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
          onPressed: () {
            
            _doSomething();

            // Hide the keyboard
            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
         },
     ),


You can wrap your main content in a SingleChildScrollView to avoid to bottom overflow issue when the keyboard appears.

Use a SingleChildScrollView around your widget, keep resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true
SingleChildScrollView(
    // Make sure the SingleChildScrollView has a padding at the bottom equal to the keyboard height
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)
    child: ...

